# CurrentMember.Children losts the context

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, data-warehouse, olap

I have a simple query like that:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Condition] AS -some-logic-
SET [Items] AS FILTER([Item].[Group - Item].CurrentMember.Children, [Condition])
MEMBER [Some Metric] AS SUM([Items], [Usages])
SET [Groups] AS NonEmpty([Item].[Group - Item].[Group], [Cost])
SELECT
  [Some Metric] ON COLUMNS,
  [Groups] ON ROWS
FROM [Spend]
WHERE (FiltrationMember1, FiltrationMember2)
```

The result of this query is always null and it seems like the member [Some Metric] cannot precalculate set of Items before. Like it is lost the context of ".CurrentMember". And thats why I think so, for example, if I change the [Some Metric] member to:

```
MEMBER [Some Metric] AS SUM(FILTER([Item].[Group - Item].CurrentMember.Children, [Condition]), [Usages])
```

It starts working as expected: I get Groups on rows but the related values are calculated not by whole group but by several items which satisfy the condition filter.

I tried to use EXISTING function on my set as long as I see in MSDN it helps to force to use current context but no luck. It really makes me think that I cannot use CurrentMember on the second+ levels of calculated members, am I right?

Comment: Where did you use the Existing keyword?

Comment: @DanyloKorostil In FILTER expression. Just followed an example from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/mdx/mdx-query-existing-keyword)

Comment: Use it in SUM() expression instead.

Comment: @DanyloKorostil unfortunately result is the same. Moreover the query execution time had increased on 6000%.

Comment: You have to create a clone to [Item].[Group - Item] attribute and use it instead.